# What type of query would be suitable for returning results based on certian user input?

Tags: mysql

Ok so for example is a user typed in Strawberry a simple sql query would be suffice. However if a user typed in Strawberries what would be a suitable query to return results based on Strawberries and Strawberry and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME='Strawberry' OR COLUMN_NAME='Strawberries';
```

Comment: That works for specific example but as OP is dealing with dynamic data submitted by end users who are only going to type in 1 word, it will not work..

Comment: But how is the user submitting data, is there like a form in place? If that's the case, then the syntax will be different.  I've just typed the above based on what I understood from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad Sohail Arif's answer is not wrong, but personally I find this more useful:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'Strawberr%'
```

If that's not good enough for you, then you have the following options:

1. Restrict the input that users are allowed to enter in the first place.
2. Implement linguistic analysis on the user input.  (Begin by securing a Ph.D. research grant.)