# Get latest result in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have following table structure:

```
id    customer_id    version_num
1         1              1
2         1              2
3         2              1
4         2              2
5         3              1
6         3              2
7         3              3
```

I want results to be displayed as:

```
id    customer_id    version_num
2         1              2
4         2              2
7         3              3
```

I'm able to get the following results:

```
id    customer_id    version_num
1         1              1
3         2              1
5         3              1
```

Query that I used:

```
select * from TABLE group by customer_id
```

I don't know how to make use of latest(version_num) in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Y.id, Y.customer_id, Y.version_num
FROM YourTable Y
JOIN (SELECT customer_id, MAX(version_num) max_v
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP  customer_id
     ) T
  ON Y.customer_id = T.customer_id
 AND Y.version_num = T.max_v;
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Strawberry Is right I got cought in mySql bad habits. Previous version returns random id. The edited version is what you want.

Comment: @Strawberry I think the question in the following link has been reserved for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34070064